# why my code takes too long to execute in Python graphics?

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw a specific pattern in a 100x100 window using John Zelle’s graphics module, however, my code runs really slowly and executes the program partly. I am sure that the nested for loop is not the most efficient way to do it, but I don't know any other way to alternate the colors

. Any thoughts? Here is the code:

```js
from graphics import*
def drawCircle(win,center,radius,colour):
    c = Circle(center,radius)
    c.draw(win)
    c.setFill(colour)
    return(c)
def drawFourcircleTF(win,x,y,color,color2):
    square = drawsquare(x,y,win,color2)
    for X in range(x+5,x+20,10):
        for Y in range(y+5,y+20,10):
           circle = drawCircle(win,Point(X,Y),5,color)
def drawsquare(x1,y1,win,color):
    r = Rectangle(Point(x1,y1),Point(x1+20,y1+20))
    r.draw(win)
    r.setOutline(color)
    r.setFill(color)
    return r

def Penultimatedigitdesign(x,y,win,color):
    for Y in range(y,y+100,40):
        for X in range(x+20,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleTF(win,X,Y,"white",color)
        for X in range(x,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleTF(win,X,Y,color,"white")
    for Y in range(y+20,y+100,40):
        for X in range(x+20,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleTF(win,X,Y,color,"white")
        for X in range(x,x+100,40):
            drawFourcircleTF(win,X,Y,"white",color)
```

This is the pattern I'm trying to do :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHFcQ.png)

Comment: You don't call any of your functions :)

Comment: Can you please explain, cause i called the drawFourCircleTF function

Comment: You only define 4 functions. The fact that one calls others is not relevant, when it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. It's just you don't call your *Penultimatedigitdesign* function (at least in the above snippet). Also, allow the program to wait for the window to be visible.

Considering the snippet is in a (*.py*) file (in my case, it's *code00.py*), add these lines at the end of it (the *__main__* part doesn't need to be so complex, it's just some template that I use):

```py
def main(*argv):
    win = GraphWin("Pattern", 200, 200)
    Penultimatedigitdesign(50, 50, win, "red")
    input("Press <Enter> to exit...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

[image: Img0]